# Pandas read_csv with column behind value

Tags: pandas, dataframe, read-csv

I want to read a csv file with following structure:

```
1 file, 13 insertions, 23 deletions
1 file, 43 deletions
2 file, 7 insertions
4 file, 13 insertions, 45 deletions
```

I would like to get a Dataframe, which should look following:

```
file   insertions  deletions
1      13          23
1      0           43
1      7           0
4      13          45
```

Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: Is it csv file or a text file?

Comment: It is a string, but I use read_csv(StringIO(...))

Comment: @Sirdrakeistda be careful with the `unstack` approach, this currently has an open bug (I added details in the answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read your file, split the values with [`extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) (or [`split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html)), then [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', sep=', *')
out = (df.stack().str.extract(r'(\d+) *(.*)')
         .droplevel(-1).pivot(columns=1, values=0)
         .fillna(0).rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
        #.astype(int) # optional, to convert strings to integers
      )
```

*NB. to use `split`, replace `.str.extract(r'(\d+) *(.*)')` with `.str.split(' +', n=1, expand=True)`.*

Output:

```
  deletions file insertions
0        23    1         13
1        43    1          0
2         0    2          7
3        45    4         13
```

Variant with [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) to keep the original order of columns:

```
out = (df.stack().str.extract(r'(\d+) *(.*)')
         .droplevel(-1)
         .set_index(1, append=True)[0]
         .unstack(fill_value=0, sort=False)
         .rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
      )
```

Output:

```
  file insertions deletions
0    1         13        23
1    1         43         0
2    0          2         7
3    4         13        45
```

*NB. I just realized that the output with `unstack` is incorrect when using `sort=False` [which seems to be a bug](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/55516).*